# ASP.NET Web Forms - Send Ajax from Page.aspx to other Different.cs/MethodName

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, webforms

How can I call a (static[WebMethod]) method() located inside a different page than the one calling the ajax function?
The page is also using a master page setup.

- **Want to call:** *root/Controllers/MyController.cs/method()*
- **From:** *root/Pages/MyPage.aspx*
- **Master:** *root/Pages/Master/MasterIndex.master*

**MyController inherits : Page** (but doesn't have a forward .aspx view) and has this method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void HelloWorld(string txt) // , string[] parameters
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HelloWorld: " + txt);
}
```

I've been trying this on the MyPage.aspx:

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "Controllers/MyController/HelloWorld",
       type: "POST",
       error: function () {
         alert('error');  <-- only enters here
       },
       success: function () {
         alert('success');
       }
...
```

But no matter how I adjust the path with ../../, ~/, .cs, I can't seem to reach it.

This is a web forms project, but I want to have a centralized controller - and I can't convert the project to MVC.

Comment: Is there a reason you particularly don't want your "controller" to be an aspx page? Because probably that's the simplest solution here. When I've used web methods with ajax like you are trying to, I just had them in a page with an aspx front end.

Comment: In your IIS configuration, take a look at "Handler mappings". This section shows what file extensions are served by the IIS and you'll find that ".cs" is not one of them. Put your code into aspx page or other file type that's served by IIS

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we don't care about controllers and what not. We using web forms, and we want to call + use a web method in another page. Sure, in fact I tend to place the required web methods in the same page - not used a "asmx" page as a result in years and years.

And you are most certainly free to consume or call webmethods you have in any page in the site.

So, the problem really comes down to getting the correct path name. But, what happens if we are a few folders down (or up) from that page? I kind of don't really want to worry, and worse yet, getting the URL path can be a pain. So, the REAL goal here is to remove that pain point, and not have to worry about the URL!!

So, I suggest this code:

```
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
            Text="Web method call (ajax)" CssClass="btn"
            OnClientClick="MyTestWeb();return false"/>

    </div>

    <script>

        function MyTestWeb() {
            tBox = $('#TextBox1')
            URL = '<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Grids/Test1.aspx/HelloWorld") %>' 

            alert(URL)   // testing - remove when happy

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {
                    // ok, have return value, place in 
                    // TextBox1
                    tBox.val(data.d)
                }
            });
        }
```

So, we get the correct working URL with above. In asp.net code, you can resolve path names from the root with "~/", but such expressions don't work in JavaScript. (nor in client side controls either for that matter).

So, I use the above server side expression - it will get me the correct url each time.

For this test, my page was inside of a folder called Test4.

but, the web method page was inside of a folder called Grids.

So, the returned URL actually becomes this:

[image]

Note how we corked down one level with "..". but, really who cares what the correct URL supposed to be, I only care that I get one, and I can type in a EASY url that I know will work.

So, I suggest you try the above - and display the correct URL, then you can type that in, or just continue to the use the above idea.

The web method in that other page was this:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function HelloWorld() As String

    Dim str As String = "Hello world"

    Return str

End Function
```

So, when I run the above, I get/see this:

[image]

So, at the very least, try using that server side expression to resolve the URL, pop a alert box, and see what it spits out. (but, really, you don't have to care what it spits out - as long as it works - right?).

is the static web method in the master page, or a simple aspx page? You don't have to care about the master page in this case, since you only wanting to use + consume the web method in the code behind for that given page. If the code behind (web method) is in the master page (assuming you using them), then you use the path to the master page - which would be in the root of the applcation. However, the above path name resolve suggestion will still work just fine.

So, in your case, the path name is this:

```
root/Controllers/MyController.cs/method()
```

So, in js code, then this should work:

```
URL = '<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Controllers/MyController.aspx/HelloWorld") %>'
```